# Issue creating RSA key with small primes in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa

I want to write a .net based solution to the Cicdia 2012 triange puzzle.
http://uncovering-cicada.wikia.com/wiki/The_Triangle_Puzzle

Unfortunately, I keep getting the error "bad data" when creating an RSA key with the prime numbers from the solution:

```
 RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = new RSAParameters();
        RSAKeyInfo.Exponent = BigInteger.Parse("65537").ToByteArray();
        RSAKeyInfo.P = BigInteger.Parse("99554414790940424414351515490472769096534141749790794321708050837").ToByteArray();
        RSAKeyInfo.Q = BigInteger.Parse("104593961812606247801193807142122161186583731774511103180935025763").ToByteArray();

        RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);
```

I understand the basics of asymetric encryption, but I cant understand why I cant create my own key with small primes... unless the  RSACryptoServiceProvider has some kind of "strength checker" or something.

Comment: You are missing a bunch of fields for the RSAParameter struct. What happens if you supply them all?

Comment: Also, RSAParameters fields are *evidently* big-endian, but BigInteger.ToByteArray [returns values in little-endian order](http://blog.wezeku.com/2011/03/12/net-rsaparameters-endianness/).

Comment: p and q input are 65 and 66 characters long. If I make them 64 and 65, it works. Could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an some example code illustrating my comments.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = new RSAParameters();
        BigInteger p = BigInteger.Parse("99554414790940424414351515490472769096534141749790794321708050837");
        BigInteger q = BigInteger.Parse("104593961812606247801193807142122161186583731774511103180935025763");
        BigInteger modulus = p * q;
        BigInteger e = BigInteger.Parse("65537");
        BigInteger d = BigInteger.Parse("3198894071003639550820071093788580812499328515050919260466968671765341413862337988421155590663267840745788239672194253184260553629");
        BigInteger dp = d % (p - 1);
        BigInteger dq = d % (q - 1);
        BigInteger inverseQ = BigInteger.ModPow(q, p - 2, p);

        RSAKeyInfo.Modulus = SwapEndian(modulus.ToByteArray());
        RSAKeyInfo.Exponent = SwapEndian(e.ToByteArray());
        RSAKeyInfo.P = SwapEndian(p.ToByteArray());
        RSAKeyInfo.Q = SwapEndian(q.ToByteArray());
        RSAKeyInfo.D = SwapEndian(d.ToByteArray());
        RSAKeyInfo.DP = SwapEndian(dp.ToByteArray());
        RSAKeyInfo.DQ = SwapEndian(dq.ToByteArray());
        RSAKeyInfo.InverseQ = SwapEndian(inverseQ.ToByteArray());
        RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
        rsa.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }

    private static byte[] SwapEndian(byte[] v0)
    {
        byte[] v = (byte[])v0.Clone();
        int i = 0;
        int j = v.Length - 1;
        while (i < j)
        {
            byte t = v[i];
            v[i] = v[j];
            v[j] = t;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: Does this code actually work for you?  I've copied and pasted it, and I still get the same error.

Comment: Yes, I ran this code on my mac with Mono and it worked. I just copy&pasted it from here to double-check and it worked the same.

Comment: OK, the above code doesnt seem to work for me... however, I have noticed something odd

 BigInteger modulus = p * q;
            RSAKeyInfo.Modulus = SwapEndian(modulus.ToByteArray());

Seems to cause an issue... I've generated a valid private key, by exporting from RSA, if I run those lines above, the byte array generated in Modulus by RSA is different to the byte array generate by the above lines.

Comment: If you generate a RSA key then the values will be different. Perhaps you mean something else?

Comment: What I mean is, I stored the actual p and q values for a generated key into the p and q variables.